# Cannot bring image to front in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I've some troubl to bring a FarbicJS element to the front of the canvas.

After a few web browsing I've found this post : [Control z-index in Fabric.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131206/control-z-index-in-fabric-js)
Howerver it seems to have absolutely no effect in my code.

EDIT : [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461421/fabric-js-layering-text-over-images-on-a-canvas) also bring some other solutions but no effect either.

I may have done a silly mistake but I can't figure out where. Here is my code (at least, the relevant part) :

```
//first image, well displayed and functionnal
fabric.Image.fromURL(sourceImg, function(img){
    //don't pay attention to following properties
    img.left = YYY
    img.top = XXX
    img.width = whatever
    img.height = whatever
    img.rega = something

    //big animation part
    img.on('mouseover', function(){
        //blabla
    });
    that.canvas.add(img);
});

//second image (text), not displayed
var myText = new fabric.Text("SI REGA2", {
    //some properties...
    left: YYY //    Here coordonnates of the text are the same
    top: XXX  //    than first image's coordonnates.
    selectable: false,
    hasControls: false,
    hasBorders: false,
    fontSize: 20
});
this.canvas.add(myText); //adding text to the canvas...
this.canvas.bringToFront(myText); //... and bringing back to the front in order to place it over the first image
```

There is no error in the console, so I think all is going well, but the text is not displayed. Or at least under the first image.

What should I do ?

Comment: do you use F12 from webbrowser?

Comment: yep, fantastic tool. Here it doesn't appear but I've tried to `console.log(myText)` and the object seem to be OK. That's what lead me to think that the text is added to the canvas but bellow the image.

Comment: hmm... i can only wish you good luck then! or provide small working sample with isolates your error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why, but executing `canvas.sendToBack(img);`, will put the text in front of the image. `canvas.sendToFront(myText);` won't though. So the code beneath will put the text in front of the image:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabric');
canvas.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
canvas.renderAll();

fabric.Image.fromURL("https://placehold.it/200x200", function(img){
    img.left = 0;
    img.top = 0;
    img.width = 200;
    img.height = 200;

    canvas.add(img);
    //Where the magic happens
    canvas.sendToBack(img);
});

var myText = new fabric.Text("SI REGA2", {
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    selectable: false,
    hasControls: false,
    hasBorders: false,
    fontSize: 20
});
canvas.add(myText);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0rw98wws/)

Comment: The reason is explained in the [answer of mpedersen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41834619/57091).

Answer (score 2):

This question has been long answered, but I thought I could add some more information as I've just started tinkering with FabricJS.

The behavior seen here is due to the fact that `fabric.Image.fromURL()` works **asynchronously** (the callback function hints to this). So, the `myText`object is added to the canvas first, *then* the image second.

FabricJS determines z-index by the order added to the canvas, so it makes sense that the image overlaps the text.

Check out the console in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpedersen15/0rw98wws/2/) to see that the text is added before the image and that the `myText` object is available within the `fabric.Image.fromURL` callback.